# How can I resize a texture in Blender?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

It has been a while I am trying to solve the problem. The thing is my Mapping node seems not to have any effect at all on the object. I wish to resize my texture (to diminish it and repeat it), but I have followed many ways to do it by searching on Google and none has got any reaction on my software. I guess something isn't switched in as it should:

[image: I do put a screenshot but it might not be useful]

Comment: `I have followed many ways to do it by searching on Google` Sure, but since you don't tell us what you tried and what you get, we can't really do anything but blind guessing...

Comment: Maybe you are indeed scaling the texture but the viewer in render mode doesn't refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resize a texture you need to increase/decrease its scale in the mapping node. Repeat works when scale is greater than 1.0